# VBScript / WshShell - Click Button with no name, id, or class

Tags: vbscript, wsh

I want to use VBScript to click a button that reads “Add Document” in the GUI of an application that runs in Internet Explorer. The problem is there is no “id”, “name” , or “class” element in the source code (see below) to use as a reference in the script.

```
Source Code:

       <TD>
<INPUT type="button" value="Add Document" onclick="addFileUploadBox()">
       </TD>
```

My code is below and works for elements that have source code ids.  Also included are some failed attempts to click the button in question based on my googling but I cant get to work. I'm new to this and any help would be appreciated - any suggestions to fix?

```
    My Code:

    Dim objIE
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    objIE.Visible = True

    objIE.Navigate "http://sharemxxxx.xxxxx.com/xxxImport/import.aspx"

    While objIE.Busy
      WScript.Sleep 100
    Wend

    objIE.Document.getElementById("txtReferenceNum").value = "15226002"

    objIE.Document.getElementById("ddlCategory").value = "05"

    objIE.Document.getElementById("btnRetrieve").click

    ' ABOVE CODE WORKS

    ' NOT WORKING #1 - DOES NOTHING - NO ERROR
    '===========================================

    objIE.Document.getElementByType("btn").Value="Add Document"

    For Each btn In objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
        If btn.Value="Add Document"Then btn.Click()
    Next

    ' NOT WORKING #2 - DOES NOTHING - NO ERROR
    '===========================================
    For Each Button In objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
     If Button.Value="Add Document"Then Button.Click()
    Next

    ' NOT WORKING #3 - DOES NOTHING - NO ERROR
    '===========================================
Set oInputs = objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")

    For Each elm In oInputs
               If elm.Value = "Add Document" Then
                  elm.Click
                    Exit For
                End If
           Next

    ' NOT WORKING #4 - Show Empty Msg Box
    '===========================================
    set objButtons = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")

    for each objButton in objButtons
            strText = objButton.innerhtml
            msgbox strText
            if (strText = "Add Document") then
                    msgbox "found the button!"
                    objButton.click
                    exit for
            end if
    next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't even need to find the element. It looks like the button just calls a JavaScript function. So you can use the `execScript()` function to run it.

For example:

```
objIE.Document.parentWindow.execScript "addFileUploadBox();", "javascript"
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I took out parenthesis per an error msg and then your code runs the function --- but repeats the result vs. what would occur when the button is clicked. That is, when the button is clicked it causes a few controls to be displayed but when the function is run I get 3 sets of these controls ... as if the button was clicked 3 times. I added long sleep times after function call to test but still always get the 3 sets. Any ideas?

Comment: Right on, I had some other For Each code that should have been commented out. This now works, really appreciate your help -- especially as other stuff I had read seemed to suggest could not run the function. Answer accepted!